# VBA Strange pop-up asking for input file

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops

I'm using the following loop to run through pre-defined sheets, but if I include `"ABC"` as part of the array, I will always get a pop-up window as if I have to input a file. If `"ABC"` is removed there will be no pop-up. Does anyone know what is the cause?

```
Dim nTable As Variant
 nTable = Array("Table 1", "Table 2", "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 8", _
"Table 11", "Table 12", "Table 13", "ABC") 

For w = LBound(nTable) To UBound(nTable)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(nTable(w))
            'input any statement, I used autofit as an example
            .Range("A2:AR1800").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet 1'!A2),"""", 'Sheet 1'!A2)"
            .Range("AM2:BK1800").Formula = "=IF('" & .Name & " S'!N2 =""S"", ""S"", """")"
            .Range("AT2:AU1800").Formula = "='Sheet 1'!BA2"
            .Range("A1:BL1").Columns.AutoFit

    End With
Next w
```

Comment: Maybe there is code in the sheet "ABC" firing if you change something

Comment: @Storax no the sheet is empty with just the header filled. All sheets are identical with the same first row. The code just doesn't pass "ABC"

Comment: I am talking about the code module of the sheet

Comment: @Storax All sheets are newly created, I have a code right above the problematic one that creates the sheets. Therefore there is no module assigned to ABC. It is an empty sheet.

Comment: Ok, then I do not have an idea because your code is running fine for me. Or do you have code in the workbook module firing for sheet  "ABC"?

Comment: An 'input popup' can occur when you have a formula or query that contains an unresolvable reference.

Comment: @Storax I revised my post, I left out something by accident. Now I think the error can be regenerated.

Comment: The sheet is definitely called "ABC" on its tab? Or rather, `ABC S` as that's what's referred to in the 2nd .Formula line

Comment: What is "Sheet 1"? Is it a sheet in your `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: @Storax "Sheet 1" is before "Table 1" could that be the problem?

Comment: No, as Jeeped said, I assume there is an unresolvable reference in your formulas. But why it only ocurrs for "ABC", I do not see at the moment resp. I get the popup  for `"=IF('" & .Name & " S'!N2 =""S"", ""S"", """")"` for every sheet. Why do you add an S to the sheet name?

Comment: But you did not say that you have additonal sheets ending with an S

Comment: @Storax the sheet with a trailing "S" are other sheets after "ABC", but there is no sheet names "ABC S"

Comment: Yes, I understand, but you did not give all relevant information!

Comment: @Storax I could not spot the error, didn't even know that is relevant.

Comment: Then, how did you setup the formula? You must have added the S by intention.

Comment: @Storax I changed the way how to populate formulas. The way the formula is populated is not as uniform as before. Therefore I had to change the loop defining different sheets for different formulas.

Comment: @Storax it was by intention in the start, but as I change the way how formulas are distributed , my first insight no longer applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's probably this line:

`.Range("AM2:BK1800").Formula = "=IF('" & .Name & " S'!N2 =""S"", ""S"", """")"`

Are all your other sheets named `Table 1 S`, `Table 2 S` etc... but `ABC` just named

`ABC`

and not

`ABC S` ?

Comment: you are a genius.. I think this maybe the problem

Comment: Nah I've just seen this pop up a few times making my own code and know to carefully scan the sheet names in the formula! I knew it wasn't Sheet 1 reference since the other sheets all work, it's only the ABC sheet that fell down...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ActiveWorkbook has a sheet called `Sheet 1`, this should work...

Also, use For Each loop instead, easy to read and follow...

```
Dim nTable As Variant, tbl
nTable = Array("Table 1", "Table 2", "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 8", _
"Table 11", "Table 12", "Table 13", "ABC")

For Each tbl In nTable
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tbl)
        .Range("A2:AR1800").Formula = "=IF(ISBLANK('Sheet 1'!A2),"""", 'Sheet 1'!A2)"
        .Range("AM2:BK1800").Formula = "=IF('" & .Name & "'!N2 =""S"", ""S"", """")"
        .Range("AT2:AU1800").Formula = "='Sheet 1'!BA2"
        .Range("A1:BL1").Columns.AutoFit
    End With
Next tbl
```

Comment: Thank you! Should have converted to a for loop in the beginning.